# Почему люди путают цифры и числа?

Tags: выбор-слова, словоупотребление, словоприменение

Очень часто наблюдаю во всевозможных источниках, что люди почему-то путают понятия `число` и `цифра`.
Например:

> - 3 млрд. - очень большая **цифра** для ...
> - Хотелось бы озвучить **цифру**...
>     *И дальше называют **число**.*

*Этот кошмар можно услышать почти каждый день в новостях даже на федеральных каналах.*

Однако люди не путают понятия, которые соотносятся приблизительно так же, например: `слово` и `буква`.

Вопрос: почему именно `число` и `цифра`?
Есть ли какие-либо объективные причины / исторические предпосылки / иное?

*Я было предположил, что это из-за того, что есть аж 10 чисел, которые выражаются одной цифрой. Однако и однобуквенные слова тоже есть.*

Comment: Потому что в школе не объясняют разницы, в отличие от букв и слов

Comment: В статистике, цифра - статистический показатель. Так что, первый пример верен. Цифра в статистике - это не обязательно, количество. Это может быть, например, процент, доля и т.д.

Comment: Справедливости ради надо сказать, что язык допускает и замену _слова_ на _букву_.  Например, как во фразеологизме _буква закона_ или во фразе _следуя духу, а не букве соглашения_. То есть у слова _буква_ тоже есть второе значение: то, что написано буквами.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Тут дело не в неграмотности населения, а в многозначности слова,точнее в расширении значения в языке. Посмотрите в словарь.
Значение слова **Цифра** по Ефремовой:

> Цифра - 1. Знак для обозначения числа. 
>   2. разг. **Сумма, число**.

Значение слова **Цифра** по Ожегову:
Цифра - **Показатель, расчет чего-нибудь, выраженный в числах**

Цифра Знак, обозначающий число

Возможно, переносить второе значение в письменную речь рановато, но, видимо, тенденция уже налицо, поскольку зафиксирована даже в словаре.

Answer (score 10):

**Короткий ответ**
Люди в обиходной речи  часто путают/смешивают понятия, которые близко связаны. Если такой точности достаточно в контексте той информации, в которой она используется - то по факту словоупотребления остаётся лишь констатировать тот факт что да, эти понятия путают.

**Развёрнутый ответ**
Я думаю смысла объяснять, почему путают понятия числа и цифры нет. Поставьте мысленный эксперимент - от вас зависит судьбы человечества, на нас летят инопланетяне - а так вышло, что только вот именно вы сейчас возле Самой Главной Пушки. И вот вам звонит их центра кто-то и говорит "Сейчас я вам продиктую координаты главного крейсера противника. Записывайте цифры!"

Я сомневаюсь, что вы положите трубку, потому что ясный же пень, что имеются-то ввиду числа. А почему вы не положите трубку? А потому что вам из контекста ясно, что имеется ввиду.

В целом для обывательского словоупотребления (и я не произношу в слово `обывательский` с какой-то презрительной ухмылкой) не такое уж редкое явление неправильное словоупотребление.

Мой любимый пример - слово `плечо`. В анатомическом смысле `плечо` - это вот эта вот часть руки (рисунок [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0))):

[image]

Та же часть, которую называют плечом в обиходной речи - это часть "настоящего" плеча и даже надплечья.

Тот факт, что мы живём в мире, где есть вопиюще неточные статьи вроде "Пуля попала ему в плечо", "как накачать мышцы плеч" - живём и как-то не цивилизация не гибнет - свидетельство того, что нужно проще относится к таким вещам.

Comment: Ну допустим, предложение записывать цифры очевидно корректно интерпретируется, если после этого не следует секвенция типа "А теперь цифра сто двадцать восемь"...

Answer (score 5):

1. Мне кажется, у обиходно употребляемого так слова "цифра" смысл более узкий, чем у слова "число". Оно означает "число, имеющее некую материальную значимость или важность". Вряд ли при каком угодно градусе разговорности доведется услышать, что "цифра 13 несчастливая".
2. У слова "число" в той же обиходной речи настолько преобладает значение "день месяца", что "правильное" употребление даже немного сбивает с толку: "число? при чем тут календарь? а, в смысле *цифра*".

Answer (score 2):

В статистике, цифра - статистический показатель. Так что, первый пример верен. Цифра в статистике - это не обязательно, количество. Это может быть, например, процент, доля, соотношение, корреляция, прирост, долг и т.д. Может быть и количество, и число.

Число же - это количество физических единиц. Это даже более узко, чем количество. Может быть количество денег, но не может быть числа денег (а вот число грузовиков может быть).

Может быть цифра долга, но не может быть количества долга и числа долга.

Может быть цифра денег на счету (усреднённая или на конец года), может быть количество денег на счету, но не может быть числа денег на счету.