# "Имя числительное" или "номер"?

Tags: числительные, математика

Какая разница между словами "числительные" и "номера"?

Comment: Я имею в виду, какая есть разница когда мы говорим о номерах, которые мы считаем или употребляем в математике? Например, лучше сказать "Он видит все номера на доске." или "Он видит все числительные на доске."?

Comment: В математике нет ни номеров, как определённой сущности, ни числительных. Но есть числа. Поэтому лучше сказать "Он видит все числа на доске".

Comment: Так что, символ "1" -- это число, а слово "один" -- это "номер"?

Comment: Слово "один" - это числительное. Но при чём здесь математика? Пожалуйста, вместо уточнения в комментариях, отредактируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы был понятен его контекст.

Comment: "числительное" это лингвистическое понятие и ни в каком контексте в математике не используется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итак, есть четыре основных связанных с понятием number термина:

1. Цифра - знак для числа, подобно тому, как буква - знак для звука (1, 2, 0);
2. Число - собственно, математическое понятие;
3. Номер - число, приписанное определённому объекту, обычно порядковое (дом номер 2 и т.п.);
4. Числительное (также известное как имя числительное) - одна из традиционно выделяемых частей речи, в которую входят слова, значение которых соответствует числам.

Итак, являющееся числительным слово "два" и цифра 2 оба обозначают число, равное количеству рук у здорового человека. И при этом какому-то объекту может быть присвоен номер два (второй номер).

Comment: Объяснение о словах "номер" и "числительный" понятно. А по поводу слов "число" и "цифра", являются ли они синонимами иногда? Например, можно перевести английское предложение "He wrote down the number 10." как "Он записал число 10." и как "Он записал цифру 10."?

Comment: @nanananana К сожалению, можно: https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/13734/3680

Comment: @Dmitry, я не уверен, поймёт ли автор, почему вы указали "к сожалению". Поясняю: в нормальном случае цифрой называют далее неделимый знак, подобно букве (то есть 10 - это две цифры, а не одна). Но на практике носители смешивают употребления и действительно говорят о, например, "цифре 10" (что технически некорректно).
Реже встречается также смешение, когда цифрой называют само число ("сложи цифры 27 и 35" с ожиданием ответа 62 - корректного на самом деле только для чисел), но так делать тем более не стоит.

Comment: @Viridianus Всё понятно. "Цифра" относится к английскому слову "digit", но употребляется иногда в разговорных контекстах с значением "число". Таким образом, у слова "цифра" более широкое употребление, чем английское слово "digit", которое только употребляется с буквальным значением слова "цифра", и не имеет разговорного употребления для обозначения "number".

Answer (score 1):

"имя числительное" - грамматический термин, и нигде более не встречается.
"номер" - фактически, это чаще нечто вещественное... нарисованное на чем-то;  чаще. И как числительное - это порядковое, а не количественное. Хотя встречаются и идиомы (или неправильное использование,ставшее идиоматичным, или метафоры) вроде "Он номер один тут" - в смысле "первый". :>

"лучше сказать "Он видит все номера на доске."" - это не про математику, а лишь про какой-то список под номерами. На той доске.

"Он видит все числительные" -  и это не про математику, а про грамматику. И даже не про цифры. :>

"Он видит все цифры", или "Он видит все числа" - вот это про математику.